# Is every $S$-unit an algebraic integer?

Tags: algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a number field, i.e. a finite algebraic extension of the rational numbers, $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $B$ be the ring of algebraic integers, i.e. the set of members of $K$ satisfying a monic polynomial equation with coefficients in $\mathbb{Z}$. Let $S$ be a finite set, of cardinality $s$, of non-trivial absolute values of $K$, including all the Archimedean absolute values. Let $K'$ be the set of non-zero members of $K$ whose absolute value is $1$ for every absolute value not in $S$. A member of $K'$ is called an $S$-unit of $K$. My question is “Is $K$ contained in $B$? i.e. is every $S$-unit an algebraic integer?”  If this statement is true, I’d like to find a proof that does not use the Dirichlet $S$-unit theorem or Minkowski theory, since I am trying to find a Minkowski-free proof of Dirichlet’s $S$-unit theorem. Algebraic methods are fine or general topology, including adeles and ideles. If this statement is not true, I’d like to find information about the coefficients of the field polynomial or the minimal polynomial of an element $x$ of $K'$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, especially about absolute lower bounds of the coefficients if we restrict our attention to those x for which all the absolute values in S are bounded.

Here is as far I have reached: Let $S'$ be the set of non-Archimedean absolute values in $S$. Each of these absolute values corresponds to a prime ideal in $B$, which lies over a prime ideal in $\mathbb{Z}$, generated by a prime number $p$. Let $P$ be the set of all such prime numbers. Let $f(X)$ be the field polynomial of an element $x$ of $K'$. Thus $f(X)$ is monic with rational coefficients. I can show that the constant term in $f(X)$ is a product of primes in $P$ raised to integral powers. Since the field polynomial is a power of the minimal polynomial of $x$ over $\mathbb{Q}$, the same result holds for the constant term of the minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 4):

I think you mean to write "is $K'$ contained in $B$". (You left off the prime.) A more typical notation for $S$-units is $R_S$ or $B_S$. Anyway, the answer is no. Indeed, take $K=\mathbb Q$, so $B=\mathbb Z$, and $S=\{\infty,2\}$. Then $B_S$ (your $K'$) is $\mathbb Z[\frac12]$, so $\frac12$ is an $S$-unit, but it's not an (algebraic) integer. In fact, since $b$ is an $S$-unit if and only if $1/b$ is an $S$-unit, if the answer to your question were yes, then every $S$-unit would be in $B^*$, i.e., would be a regular unit.

BTW, this question may well be closed, since it's rather elementary, so probably belongs on MathStackExchange.

Comment: The negative answer would seem to invalidate a proof of Lang and Weston of the discreteness of the log representation of the  S-units. I'll post a separate question about that soon. Thanks for the counter-example.

Comment: @P.Lawrence I don't know which proof you're referring to, but the usual log map for $S$-units is $$R_S^*\to\prod_{v\in S} \mathbb R^{\#S},\quad u\mapsto \bigl(\log\|u\|_v\bigr)_{v\in S},$$ and the image of this map is discrete and lies on (in fact, spans) a hyperplane determined by the product formula.

Comment: @Joe Silverman.  Let $K$ be a number field and $S$ be a finite set of places containing real places Does$2\ in S$ implies $2$ is S unit like in your answer ?

Comment: @Pont Yes, if $2\in S$, then $2\in\mathbb Z_S^*$. Explicitly, if $S=\{p_1,\dots,p_n\}$, then $\mathbb Z_S=\mathbb Z[p_1^{-1},\dots,p_n^{-1}]$, so the primes in $S$ are units in $\mathbb Z_S$.